# Excel : copy data on a separate worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a table on a worksheet (summary page), on that work sheet I have a data validation (Dropdown List). Is there a way that excel can automatically copy the entire row on worksheetA if I dropdown to itemA and to worksheetB if I dropdown to itemB and so on? The main Sheet will be the summary page which is sorted our to their respective sheets.

Comment: This can be done with VLOOKUPS and/or VBA.  What have you tried and where is it failing?

Comment: Please disregard this question. I decided to use Pivot table. This tool helped me filter what information i wanted to see and just by clicking on the total count, Excel creates a new Sheet with all the deatils specified on the filter.

Comment: feel free to delete.